# Accessing nested array of objects from dataTable row

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I have an api response of data that im using to populate a datatable. the data looks like this:

```
{
    code: 'CPX154',
    identity: '108',
    name: 'Joshua Laryea',
    created_at: '12:23 pm',
    phone: '0559546287',
    pickup: [
        {desc: 'Shirts', quantity: '15'},
        {desc: 'Suit', quantity: '2'},
        {desc: 'Jeans', quantity: '6'}
    ]
},
{
    code: 'CGH154',
    identity: '108',
    name: 'Gloria Fynn',
    created_at: '15:23 pm',
    phone: '0249563287',
    pickup: [
        {desc: 'Shirts', quantity: '5'},
        {desc: 'Trouser', quantity: '2'},
        {desc: 'Shorts', quantity: '1'},
        {desc: 'Suit', quantity: '2'},
        {desc: 'Jeans', quantity: '6'}
    ]
}
```

After doing a `JSON.parse(data)` i am able to access the data like any other normal object and have used it to populate the datatable. My issue is that on click of any of the table row, when i get access to that row's data the field `pickup` shows `[object object]` and i cannot parse it with JSON also. it results in an error.

please help

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: `[object Object]` is what you get when you convert an object to a string. Maybe you are somehow not using your object correctly, or you are just inspecting the value incorrectly and the value is actually fine but you are trying to call `JSON.parse` on an object value. We cannot really help without knowing what you are doing. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @FelixKling, thanks for the quick response. i already converted the data into object before using it to populate the table. the table someway stores all the info or data of each row and so u can get that data. but when i retrieve that data from the row, though its in an object format, only the pickup field is shown as [object object]

Comment: *"the table someway stores all the info or data of each row and so u can get that data."* This doesn't tell us anything. We really need to see your code. Please see the links I posted.

Answer (score 0):

The field pickup should be treated as an array which means you have to loop through it.

```
var mainObj = JSON.parse(data)
for(var i in mainObj){
var pickup = mainObj[i].pickup;
for(var l in pickup){
// here you can access 
// pickup.desc
// pickup.quantity
}
}
```

Comment: `pickup.desc` should be `pickup[l].desc`. But you shouldn't use `for...in` to iterate over arrays. Use `for...of`, `arr.forEach` or `for` instead.

Comment: It's not my question. I just pointed out mistakes in your answer so that you can correct them for the benefit of all future visitors. (besides I think the question contains too little information to actually provide any helpful answer)

Comment: Sorry but i already know how to loop through an array. the format of the data i get from the rows is my issue.. i try parsing it and i get errors